# Ribbon Custom Action - Upload.aspx trouble (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, ribbon, file-upload

I want to add an **"upload document button"** to listitem **DispForm.aspx**. I created ribbon custom action in my hosted application. When I press the button, opens the Upload.aspx form, but **uploadLocation** field **is empty**. 
I call Upload.aspx as

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="http://myPortal/mySite/myLists/myList/Forms/Upload.aspx?List={ListId}&ampRootFolder={RootFolder}"/>
```

It opens Upload.aspx form and it works, but it can't get the **parameter** **RootFolder**. For example, the result link is: http://myPortal/mySite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=c0e84b4a%2D92e7%2D414b%2Dacaa%2D88e98824b185&RootFolder={RootFolder}

When I manually add to this link correct RootFolder value, the field uploadLocation gets this value.

So, I've got question - how to call Upload.aspx form correctly and get parameter RootFolder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check, it seems there is error in your query string parameters.

&ampRootFolder={RootFolder}  should be &RootFolder={RootFolder}

Comment: I've changed link, but nothing has changed. Adress is still like `/Upload.aspx?List={here is id number}&RootFolder={RootFolder}&IsDlg=1` 
And the field `uploadLocation disappeared`.